# How to create a Virtualbox image from a WindowsXP (host) physical partition

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox

How to create a Virtualbox image from a WindowsXP (host) physical partition.
I want to reverse the Host--winXP and Guest--Ubuntu.
First I have to be able to create a VDI Host of my winXP fisical partition.
Who can tell me if it is possible and how to do it.
With Acronis I have already done the HD-Immagine-backup.

thank you ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has a free utility called [Disk2VHD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) that will let you create a .vhd or .vhdx file from a running Windows XP machine. It also works on Vista and later.

You should be able to just use the .vhd file if you have un-checked the "use vhdx format" box in Disk2VHD.  If you create a .vhdx file you will need to convert it before using it as a VM because VirtualBox only has read-only support for .vhdx files.

Here's a command to convert the image:

```
VBoxManage convertfromraw /path/to/VHDX /path/to/new/VDI --format VDI
```

Comment: For everything you love, don't forget to uncheck the VHDX option, which is checked by default, or you'll lose several hours of your life that will never come back.